# How to mock a class atribute

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, python-mock

I have an object like this:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(name, age):
     self.name = name
     self.age = age
     self.has_paid = False

  def paid(self):
     if condition:
      has_paid = True
```

In class B in another file, I instantiate the class

```
Class B
 self.customer = Person('Jhon', 28)
 self.paid()
 if self.has_paid:
  send_receipt()
```

I am trying to test class B using the following fixture

```
@fixture
def b_class_fixture():
    
    def _make_dummy_B_class():
        b = class_B()
        b.customer = MagicMock()
        b.customer.has_paid = MagicMock(matched=True)
        return b

    yield _make_dummy_B_class
```

In this test:

```
def test_call_dont_sent_receipt(b_class_fixture):
 b = b_class_fixture
 b.check()
 assert b.customer.has_paid== True
```

However, it is not working. Can someone please help me to achieve mocking that Person.has_paid = True

Comment: Just do `b.customer.has_paid = True` instead of `b.customer.has_paid = MagicMock(...)`.